# Add Unique ID to inputs generated with foreach by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to append unique id to input.

This is my input:

```
foreach( $subItems AS $item ) {
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_sub" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">                                                                            

    <input type="text" id="sub_min_points" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled> 
}
```

Example of generated ids:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_sub_id1" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_sub_id2" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_sub_id3" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_sub_id4" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="text" id="sub_min_points_id1" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
<input type="text" id="sub_min_points_id2" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
<input type="text" id="sub_min_points_id3" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
<input type="text" id="sub_min_points_id4" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
```

Then I want to make the input enabled if the checkbox is checked.

I used this code to make the input get enabled after checked
but the problem it's working only in the first input since the generated inputs don't have unique ids

```
$('#checkbox_sub').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    $('#sub_min_points').removeAttr('disabled');
});
$('#checkbox_sub').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
    $( '#sub_min_points_' ).attr( "disabled" , 'disabled') ;
});
```

The above code has methods from this plugin [Icheck](http://icheck.fronteed.com/)

---

Clarification of my idea:

Make unique ids for dynamically inserted inputs by foreach, then use the variable in checkbox checked and unchecked

Example:

This is only clarification, I don't know how to make it in JS
using increment value `++i` and append to the `id=""` and use the whole id after appending the increment variable to original id to change the attribute of all

```
$('#checkbox_sub+i+').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    $('#sub_min_points+i+').removeAttr('disabled');
});
$('#checkbox_sub+i+').on('ifUnchecked', function(event){
    $( '#sub_min_points+i+' ).attr( "disabled" , 'disabled') ;
});
```

what I need :

- `#checkbox_sub_1` when checked -> `#sub_min_points_1` `disabled` attribute will be removed
- `#checkbox_sub_2` when checked -> `#sub_min_points_2` `disabled` attribute will be removed
- `#checkbox_sub_3` when checked -> `#sub_min_points_3` `disabled` attribute will be removed*

Comment: Is this JSX code as well?

Comment: I will use .prop no problem  . but I'm weak at javascript i need an example and be aware about that the inputs can be increased or decreased because they auto generated depend on Database rows thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need element IDs to do this, because it is possible to write JS that says "when the *nth* one of *these* elements is clicked, update the corresponding *nth* one of *those* elements".

The following is one way to do that, making use of jQuery's [`.index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to figure out the index of the clicked checkbox, and the [`.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select the corresponding text input. Note that within the click event handler, `this` refers to the clicked element. By the way, I've assumed jQuery is OK even though the question didn't have the "jQuery" tag, because there is jQuery code shown in the question body.

Note that the `foreach()` shown in the question would output the checkboxes and text inputs in pairs, not all of the checkboxes first and then all of the text inputs as shown in the question under "Example of generated ids", so in the following demo I've used HTML that has them in pairs. But, the same JS would work just as well if you did have all the checkboxes first followed by all the text inputs, because (again) it is using the relative positions of each to decide which one to update.

```js
var cbs = $('input[name="sub_elements[]"]')
var inputs = $('input[name="sub_min_points[]"]')

cbs.on('click', function() {
  inputs.eq(cbs.index(this)).prop('disabled', !this.checked)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="text" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="text" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="text" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="text" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
```

As an aside, you should disable and enable fields with `.prop("disabled", true)` (or `false`), don't use `.removeAttr()` and `.attr()`.

A second option that would work for the HTML shown in the previous example would be to simply use the DOM navigation [`.next()` method](http://api.jquery.com/next/), because when the checkbox is clicked the associated text input is literally the next element in the DOM:

```js
$('input[name="sub_elements[]"]').on('click', function() {
  $(this).next().prop('disabled', !this.checked)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="text" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="text" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="text" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
<input type="checkbox" class=" flat"name="sub_elements[]" required="required">
<input type="text" name="sub_min_points[]" disabled>
```

Comment: Thanks So much for helping I made little edit to the code and it worked :).

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using ICheck plugin the above code needed to be edited like that to work with me

```
var cbs = $('input[name="sub_elements[]"]') ;
var inputs = $('input[name="sub_min_points[]"]') ;
cbs.on('ifChecked',  function(event) {
    inputs.eq(cbs.index(this)).prop('disabled', false)
})

cbs.on('ifUnchecked',  function(event) {
    inputs.eq(cbs.index(this)).prop('disabled', true)
})
```